# Error starting eclipse exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse

I have already searched for this but i cant find something that answer this (tried some but i dont understand how to proceed or it just dont works)
So here am I, when I launch eclipse it just doesn't start and I got this message:

[image]

If I understood well, the eclipse.ini file has something to do with the problem. Here it is:

[image]

Sorry for my language, I am not native english so, I tried to explain as best as I could.

Comment: Don't just tell us that you searched -- show us what you found and tell us why those solutions didn't work for you.

Comment: Instead of providing an image of your eclipse.ini file, copy its contents and post them in the question. This way is easier for us to read, copy and paste the necessary elements for providing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 32bit OS and you are trying to use a 64bit eclipse and/or 64bit JDK

Answer (score 0):

Before to do this i suggest to verify the type of your OS(32 or 64 bit).
-I also advise you to check the version of java and eclipse IDE that you have downloaded and installed

After this try to erase the string from your ENV path of WINDOWS from **System->Advanced settings->enviroment path** 
and erase the string C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\bin;

if it doesn't work yet try to modify your eclipse.ini like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
**-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe**
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

you must put the string before vmargs and put the correct release of java. 
Also you have to put -vm and a new line the path